# Filter "search files by name" in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-worktree

I reqularly use `ctrl+p` to open files by typing the name in VSCode. I recently started to use [Git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) in my daily work. I use VSCode's remote plugin to do my work, and since VSCode remote sessions seem to take quite a bit of resources on my PC, it is best to open just one VScode remote session in the main folder of the project, and not a separate VSCode remote session for each branch.

Here's a diagram of how the folder structure for a project with worktrees would look:

```
my_app/
├── folder1/
│   └── file1
├── file2
├── worktree_1/
│   ├── folder1/
│   │   └── file1
│   └── file2
└── worktree_2/
    ├── folder1/
    │   └── file1
    └── file2
```

VSCode does everything right in terms of version control, it successfully tracks changes in the worktrees and in the main branch.

My problem is, however, that when I press `ctrl+p` and type `file1`, VSCode suggests the file three times, from the main branch and from two worktrees. It is cognitively exhausting to filter the files by eyes, since the first suggestion usually isn't from the same worktree that my currently opened file was opened from and I usually need files from just one worktree.

So after setting the context, my question is,
**Is there any way to set a filter for the "search files by name" (`ctrl+p`) the same way that global search (`ctrl+shift+f`) can be filtered?**
So that I could set the "search files by name" to only include results from e.g. `worktree_1`? Of course I can always type `worktree_1 file1`, but that isn't very handy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by updating the vscode settings. Go to Preferences and search for "exclude" under the features section you'll find the Search option. Under *Search* just add the necessary patterns to exclude specific folders from full-text and quick searches.

[image]

Comment: This kind of works, but I would like to "include only", not exclude every worktree that I don't need.

Comment: Assuming you want this to work only with the "quick open" option, the "Find in folder" option won't be very helpful. In this scenario, the only option that comes to my mind is prefixing your searches with folder names in the quick-open option. e.g. If I start my search with "src/" it'll only look for files only inside the src directory.